# Large Scale Data Logistic Regression

Tags: r, glm, large-scale, bigdata

I have following input data:

```
head(data1)
               VarA VarB   VarC           VarD VarE  VarG  VarH VarI
2016-06-01 09:30:05 14.2  31228 ABCD IS Equity    1   139   192   23
2016-06-01 09:30:07 14.2  31128 ABCD IS Equity    0     0     0    0
2016-06-01 09:30:09 14.2  36128 ABCD IS Equity    1   138   192   23
2016-06-01 09:30:19 14.2  36028 ABCD IS Equity    0     0     0    0
2016-06-01 09:30:21 14.2  27028 ABCD IS Equity    1   112   190   23
2016-06-01 09:30:37 14.2  26528 ABCD IS Equity    0     0     0    0
```

`VarA` is of type `POSIXct`, `VarD` is of type `chr` and `rests` are of type `num`.

`VarE` is my dependent variable. `VarC, VarB, VarG, VarH and VarI` are my explanatory variables. Total row counts of the datset is `7.4 million`. I want to run logistic regression. I tried `bigglm` from `biglm` package using `binomial family`. But it is `failing to converge`. Due to which I am not getting proper deviance values. So I am having problem computing `McFadden's R-Sqr` value for the same. Can you please suggest any alternate package/way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Downvote?? May I know why?? If possible, please explain it to me, such that I can be careful next time.

Answer (score 0):

The `sgd` package will allow you to process the data sample-by-sample through the stochastic gradient descent method.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it. Though it is successfully converging, but it gives very limited information. Can you share some information about Pseudo R-Sqr computation from this only info. I could only see these info: model, coefficients, converged, estimates, pos, times, model.out.